# Unable to clone submodule in OSX

Tags: git, github, git-submodules

I'm working on a project with submodules. I've got specific branches in `.gitmodules` and I want the submodules to be checked out at specific commits. These commits are automatically stored with the parent repo.

Now if I clone the parent repo on a Linux machine (tested on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS) with `git version 2.7.4` in an empty directory, I get precisely what I intended. The output looks like this.

```
$ git clone git@github.com:redsandro/myproject.git --recursive --branch develop --single-branch
Cloning into 'myproject'...
remote: Counting objects: 105, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
remote: Total 105 (delta 11), reused 29 (delta 7), pack-reused 65
Receiving objects: 100% (105/105), 31.45 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (34/34), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule 'api' (git@github.com:redsandro/api.git) registered for path 'api'
Cloning into 'api'...
remote: Counting objects: 30647, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (137/137), done.
remote: Total 30647 (delta 96), reused 134 (delta 58), pack-reused 30442
Receiving objects: 100% (30647/30647), 4.78 MiB | 910.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (20032/20032), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
Submodule path 'api': checked out 'd651e9dd72acc4af7e3f98507373490c3be77756'
```

Now when my colleague clones the parent repo on an Apple MacBook MacOS/OSX machine with `git version 2.13.6 (Apple Git-96)` in an empty folder, I get errors on submodules, and when there is no error, there is still a mess of deletions staged.

The output looks like this:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:redsandro/myproject.git --recursive --branch develop --single-branch
Cloning into 'myproject'...
remote: Counting objects: 105, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
remote: Total 105 (delta 11), reused 29 (delta 7), pack-reused 65
Receiving objects: 100% (105/105), 31.45 KiB | 10.48 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (34/34), done.
Submodule 'api' (git@github.com:redsandro/api.git) registered for path 'api'
Cloning into '/Users/mycolleague/projects/myproject/api'...
remote: Counting objects: 1431, done.        
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1149/1149), done.        
remote: Total 1431 (delta 483), reused 640 (delta 190), pack-reused 0        
Receiving objects: 100% (1431/1431), 700.42 KiB | 1.65 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (483/483), done.
error: Server does not allow request for unadvertised object d651e9dd72acc4af7e3f98507373490c3be77756
Fetched in submodule path 'api', but it did not contain d651e9dd72acc4af7e3f98507373490c3be77756. Direct fetching of that commit failed.
```

Why is there a difference in outcome? Keep in mind that:

1. on both machines, this was tested in a new empty directory without a `.git` directory;
2. on the linux machine, this works fine.
3. The individual submodules can be cloned fine as independent projects on both Linux and OSX.

Comment: Perhaps related to Macs having a case-insensitive file system? Where the repo contains two files(/dirs) with the same name but in different case.